# How to hide folders using partition layout based on available space in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the Zoomable Icicle layout example in D3 found here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1005873 and would like to hide some sub-folders within a folder based on certain conditions i.e. if it has not been recently modified and based on available screen space (if this is possible).

I would then like the sub-folders that meet the criteria to make up the entire space underneath their parent folders, but the parent folder should have an arrow to show that there are hidden sub-folders within that folder. See the below image for clarity.[image]

I am new at using D3 and am not sure how to filter the data correctly to completely hide the other folders (although I need to be able to access these folders later as well).

Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction using the example code?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter the data to exclude the empty subfolders before you're passing it to the layout. The point of the layout is to compute the position and size of the elements given the data. So in order to have the non-hidden folders take up all available space, only pass those to the layout.

The [Javascript array `.filter()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) may be of help for what you're doing.