# D3 Partition - Show next level when clicked

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 partition which shows all the levels for the entire partition.

I would like to only show the first level when the chart loads and then show subsequent levels on click.

For example in this Tree the next level is shown on click of a node: [D3Tree](http://hacks.michelepasin.org/subjectsviz/d3tree)

Here is the code for my partition: [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fRFK4CH5ovFkfr3keA4a?p=preview)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var width = 600,
    height = 400,
    radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 10;

var formatNumber = d3.format(",d");

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { 
      if(d.depth == 2)
        console.log(d.depth, d);  

        return 1; // d.size;   

    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2) + ")");





d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
      .on("click", click)
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name + "\n" + formatNumber(d.value); });
});

function click(d) {
  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .tween("scale", function() {
        var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
            yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
            yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
        return function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); };
      })
    .selectAll("path")
      .attrTween("d", function(d) { return function() { return arc(d); }; });
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

});
```

I would like to do something like toggle on click:

```
// Toggle children.
function toggle(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
}
```

Where the children get set and unset, then redrawn

Comment: You can either call the toggle function programatically, or filter the data before passing it to the layout (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790773/how-to-hide-folders-using-partition-layout-based-on-available-space-in-d3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something like the tree layout would be a little tough doing it with the help of `display` is a a cake walk.

When the path are drawn for the first time make all the nodes whose depth > 1 disappear using `display:none`:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(partition.nodes(root))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
  })
  .style("display", function(d) {
    if (d.depth > 1) {
      return "none";//nodes whose depth is more than 1 make its vanish
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  })
```

Now on node click make all nodes reappear except when root node is clicked.

```
  .style("display", function(d1) {
    if (d.depth == 0 && d1.depth > 1) {
      return "none"//root node clicked so show only 2 depths.
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  })
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VLcgQJBoypYl0BmdewEy?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a tweening solution though this works.